# NDSolve cannot do a discontinuity replacement for event surfaces that depend only on time

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear, discontinuity

I'm trying to solve a system of DAEs with discrete conditions:

```
muk = 0.2;
mus = 0.3;
m1 = 1;
m2 = 2;
m3 = 3;
Fn12 = 3;
Fn23 = 2;
minvel = 0.1;
F1[x_] := 2*Sin[5*x];
F2[x_] := 2*Sin[7*x];
Fs12[x_] := (m2*F1[x] - m1*F2[x])/(m1 + m2);
Off[NDSolve::pdord]
s = NDSolve[{m1*x1''[t] == F1[t] - Ff12[t], x1'[0] == 0, x1[0] == 0, 
   m2*x2''[t] == F2[t] + Ff12[t], x2'[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, 
   Ff12[t] == 
    If[Abs[x1''[t] - x2''[t]] < 0.1 && Abs[Fs12[t]] < mus*Fn12 , 
     Fs12[t], muk*Fn12*Sign[x1''[t] - x2''[t]]]}, {x1, x2, Ff12}, {t, 
   10}]
```

However when solving I get two weird errors

> NDSolve::tddisc
>
> NDSolve cannot do a discontinuity replacement for event surfaces that depend only on time
>
> NDSolve::nderr
>
> Error test failure at t==...; unable to continue

[image]

which searching on google does not offer that much of the results!

I have found some relevant posts and documentations ([one](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/864111), [two](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69570/solving-a-discontinuous-differential-algebraic-equation-system-for-plasticity-be), [three](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html)). It seems that I have to use a helper function or something like that using Piecewise and/or WhenEvent functions but I can't get my head around it!

I would appreciate if you could explain why this error happens and how I can modify my code to avoid it?

Comment: It evaluates without any errors after setting `mus=10` and adding the following options to NDSolve: `Method -> {Automatic, 
  "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}, MaxStepSize -> 10^-2`. Check if this produces desired results.

Comment: @K.J. mus can't be 10, it is the static friction coefficient :) I will try the other idea now and will let you know. thanks.

Comment: @K.J. nope, not helping :(

Answer (score 2):

By trial and error, integration as far as `t == 1.3773405394574811` can be achieved with

```
s = NDSolveValue[{m1*x1''[t] == F1[t] - Ff12[t], x1'[0] == 0, x1[0] == 0, 
    m2*x2''[t] == F2[t] + Ff12[t], x2'[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0,
    Ff12[t] == If[Abs[x1''[t] - x2''[t]] < .1 && Abs[Fs12[t]] < mus*Fn12, 
    Fs12[t], muk*Fn12*Sign[x1''[t] - x2''[t]]]}, {x1, x2, Ff12}, {t, 10}, 
    MaxStepSize -> 2 10^-4];
Show[Plot[Fs12[t], {t, 0, 1.377}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed]], 
    Plot[Evaluate@Through[s[t]], {t, 0, 1.377}, PlotRange -> All],  ImageSize -> Large,
    AxesLabel -> {t, "x1, x2, Ff12, Fs12"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium]]
```

[image]

although with four messages.

> NDSolveValue::pdord: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations.
>
> NDSolve::tddisc: NDSolve cannot do a discontinuity replacement for event surfaces that depend only on time.  (*twice*)
>
> NDSolveValue::reinitfail: Unable to reinitialize the system at t = 1.3773405394574811` within specified tolerances.

Comparison between the `Ff12` curve (green) and `Fs12` curve (black dashed) suggests that `Ff12` can be approximated by

```
Ff12[t] == If[Abs[Fs12[t]] < mus*Fn12, Fs12[t], muk*Fn12*Sign[Fs12[t]]]
```

which allows integration to proceed as far as `t == 10`.

```
ss = NDSolveValue[{m1*x1''[t] == F1[t] - Ff12[t], x1'[0] == 0, x1[0] == 0, 
    m2*x2''[t] == F2[t] + Ff12[t], x2'[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0,
    Ff12[t] ==  If[Abs[Fs12[t]] < mus*Fn12, Fs12[t], muk*Fn12*Sign[Fs12[t]]]}, 
    {x1, x2, Ff12}, {t, 10}, MaxStepSize -> 10^-3]
```

A plot over the same domain as in the first plot suggests that this approximation is fairly good.

[image]

The plot over the entire domain is

[image]

This approach is by no means perfect but nonetheless produces reasonably credible results.